# Assuming pointwise convergence on $\mathbb R,$ which of the following statements are true?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

my attempt : 
i know if we take f(t) =sint as if we integerate sint from -∞ to ∞ that is int_{-∞}^{ ∞ } sint dt  = cos(-∞ ) - cos(∞)  which will give a finite value,, as i know 
 -1≤ cosx ≤ 1 ....i think option b) will be satisfied ,,so option b is correct..
i don't know about the other option a and option c ,,,

i would be thankful  for help and providing some hint or solution....

Comment: Regarding your attempt: $\cos(\infty)$ and $\cos(-\infty)$ do not exist. The function $t \mapsto \cos(t)$ oscillates and does not approach a fixed value as $|t| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, option b. is the only one that fails. To see this, let  $f_n(t) = |\sin t|\cdot\chi_{[n\pi, (n+1)\pi]}.$ Then $f_n \to 0$ pointwise everywhere, but $\int f_n = 2$ for every $n.$

Hint for a.: Fatou's lemma.

Hint for c.: Apply the dominated convergence theorem on $[a,b].$

Comment: thanks a lot @ Zhw.